# Source of a NP 47µF 60+V capacitor for audio?

Tags: capacitor, preamp

I am building a preamp which calls for a 47µF 60+V capacitor. It needs to be non-polar and being audio low ESR. (Yes, this is a 1NA217 based circuit.) The circuit requires NP caps if phantom power is not to be used. Although I am certain I do not need such a high voltage capacitor without phantom power, I may add phantom power in the future and would like to avoid having to switch out capacitors.

I need something affordable but good quality. The Nichicon aluminum organic polymers seem to be great for the price but they are polarized... I could use 4 (pair them in parallel to double the capacity, then in series (negative to negative) to make non-polars.)

Space really isn't a limitation, and although I see no issue with this technically, it still gets kind of pricey using 8 capacitors instead of the 2 the circuit requires.

Is there a better way to get NP 47µF 60+V caps with low ESR? I have searched quite a bit and I cannot find any affordable capacitors at these specs.

Comment: I still use these film caps (10uF 100V) http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ECQ-E1106KF/EF1106-ND/56416  You can search DK and find other film caps that meet your spec.  (Not cheap though)

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

1. low-ESR: Low ESR in a coupling capacitor is umm.. not very important, especially for audio. Leakage may be worth considering (especially if the leakage contributes noise). The conductive polymer caps are very leaky in comparison to cheap aluminum electrolytics.
2. Non-polarized: Phantom power has only one polarity, so you can orient the caps appropriately. As it turns out, all e-caps are non polarized for very low voltages.

Without seeing the circuit it's hard to tell, but I would think any high quality low-leakage polarized aluminum capacitor would be indistinguishable from the best capacitors you could buy.